# How to make variable inside a For Loop global or accessible within sub or another sub/form?

Tags: excel, vb.net, function, for-loop, global-variables

This is a very basic question and i have googled how to "pass variables from for loop, for each" etc... and everything just seemed ambiguous or inadequate.  Maybe because its not even possible?

I have an excel file that has a list of file numbers that i will work with later on in my code to search for PDF's in a directory.  My code works fine but my code is filled with loops, nested loops and everything always has to be within these loops because thats where the variables are declared.  Example in this code below:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1
    Dim aCell As Object = Nothing
    Dim eachcell As New List(Of String)

    Sub Main()

        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim range As Excel.Range
        Dim aCpage = "unknown"
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XBorja.RESURGENCE\Desktop\xavier.xlsx")
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
        Dim currentcell = Nothing


        For Each i In range.Value



            eachcell.Add(i)
        Next

        For Each aCell In eachcell
            currentcell = aCell.ToString
            Console.WriteLine(currentcell)
        Next

    End Sub
```

That works perfect, on the console it shows a list of all file numbers i had written in my excel sheet:

```
ZTEST01.SMITH
ZTEST14.SAMPLE05
ZTEST02.RESTAURANT
ZTEST12.SAMPLE03
ZTEST03.MCDONALD
ZTEST04.DOE
ZTEST10.SAMPLE01
ZTEST13.SAMPLE04
ZTEST11.SAMPLE02
Press any key To Continue . .
```

but if i use this code:

```
    For Each i In range.Value

        eachcell.Add(i)
    Next

    For Each aCell In eachcell
        currentcell = aCell.ToString

    Next
    Console.WriteLine(currentcell)
End Sub
```

This only tells me the last value of

```
ZTEST.11.SAMPLE02
```

I know that the logic is that since the console write is within the for loop its displaying each value in excel and appending those values to the console until the loop is finished.

My question is how would i be able to call that entire list/array *outside* the for loop?

I know with += you can add integers to get a sum in a for loop and i tried that with this code and it just gave me back all the file numbers concatenated.

Could this for loop be turned into another sub so i can call this variable "currentcell" outside of the loop?  Or could it be turned into a function So that my entire sub could always use that variable?

Comment: When you do the console.WriteLine, you already loop all the items in the list. If you wanted a string with concatenated values, then you'll need to do that (see StringBuilder). If you have a sub that needs to process all elements of the list, then you have no choice but to loop again. I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: So in here currentcell is now equal to an array {} of my file list.  How would i call that outside of the for loop?  Is there anyway that once i get all my file numbers using the for loop that i can store that array as a global variable so my other subs could use it? @the_lotus

Comment: currentcell is just a string, you want to access that string? or you want the whole list, that you already have "eachcell"?

Comment: In your example, currentcell is only equal to the last item in your list. You overwrite it on each loop. To do what you want, you would have to have a list of strings.

Comment: @DavidSdot yes, thats exactly what i want.  I would want to access that entire list (the ZTEST's numbers, all of them) outside of the for loop.

Comment: @the_lotus is there a way to take all the cell values from excel that have my file numbers and making them into a list of strings so i can access them as an array in my sub?

Comment: eachcell is already a list of strings that contains all of the files. The name isn't correct, you could call it eachFiles

Comment: @the_lotus not sure i follow.  Are you saying just to replace the word "eachcell" with "eachFiles" and that should fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iteration of the loop has it's own scope, anything local to that scope is lost after each iteration.

if your looking for a specific element you need to save it too its own value, the code you have overwrites whatever you found in the last iteration, which is why `currentcell` only had the very last value

```
Dim found As Sting
For each cell in eachCell
    If [condition] Then
        found = cell.ToString()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found is Nothing Then
    'Congrats you found it
Else
    'Too bad, not in list
End If
```

If you want to do something with more than one element you need to do that something in 
the loop, or pass the element as a parameter to a seperate function

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myArray As List(Of String);
    myArray = [get your array of elements]

    For Each item As String In myArray
        DoThing(item)
    Next

End Sub

Sub DoThing(value As String)
    Console.WriteLine(value)
End Sub
```

hopefully that helps you

Comment: YES this is exactly what i wanted.  Marked as solve.  Your comment should be highlighted as to how things should be answered around here.